# Python ,SQLalchemy, Access dbs error pop up when turn it to an exe file

Tags: python, ms-access, pyqt5, pyinstaller, sqlalchemy-access

Python ,SQLalchemy, Access dbs error pop up when turn it to an exe file

**Note**: works great in Pycharm before using Pyinstaller to turn it to an exe app. Please advise.  Tried to import sqlalchemy.dialects but still having the same issue, I'm just trying to get it work the same as when I run it in Pycharm.

```
# Error  
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 25, in <module>   File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine   File "sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py", line 277, in warned   File "sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 556, in create_engine   File "sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 754, in _get_entrypoint   File "sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 365, in load sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:access.pyodbc
```

```
# Drivers 
DRIVER = "{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}"
# DBs link
DB_URL = r"LINK_TO_MY_DATABASE"
# connection string
connection_string = f"DRIVER={DRIVER};DBQ={DB_URL};ExtendedAnsiSQL=1;"

# creating engine
connection_url = sa.engine.URL.create("access+pyodbc",query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
eng = sa.create_engine(connection_url)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "exe file" - what is file extension of database?

Comment: Like I mention before I'm using Pyinstaller to turn a script to actual app (executable) this is where the issue occur when trying to run this app, can't figure out why return that error code.

Comment: If your code does not explicitly import sqlalchemy_access then pyinstaller may not know to include it in the dependencies for the application. In that case, try adding `import sqlalchemy_access as sa_a` to your main .py file and re-build your distributable to see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you still trying to figure out what exactly the issue, still a puzzle to solve Thank you for contribution.